# How to loop through a matrix rows from i:n and columns

Tags: r, loops

I am still a beginner in r. I am trying to loop through a matrix and calculate sums looping from every single row(1:5) until the threshold (e.g. 14) within this row is reached. Then go through all columns (2:6). What I want is, that my matrix(b) is filled with the numbers(91:95), where the rows have reached the threshold.  I've tried this. Has anyone an idea, what I'm doing wrong.

```
a <- matrix(c(91:95,1:25), ncol=6)    
b <- matrix(NA,ncol=6,nrow=5)


for(i in 1:nrow(a)) {
    for(j in 2:ncol(a)) {
        for(n in 1:5) {
            if(sum(a[seq(i:n),j])>14) {
                b[i,j] <- a[n,1]
                break
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is my result.

```
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]   NA   95   93   92   91   91
[2,]   NA   NA   94   91   91   91
[3,]   NA   NA   91   91   91   91
[4,]   NA   NA   91   91   91   91
[5,]   NA   91   91   91   91   91
```

My desired result however should look like this. Results should be on the starting point(i) and show the row (n) where the threshold(14) has been exceed.

```
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]   NA   95   93   92   91   91
[2,]   NA   NA   93   93   91   91
[3,]   NA   NA   94   94   91   91
[4,]   NA   NA   95   95   91   91
[5,]   NA   NA   NA   95   91   91
```

Can anyone help me with this.

Thanks in advance. Also is easier ideas than nested loops are appreciated.

Comment: Not sure if I understood your problem, but in the 4th line of your loop should just be `i:n` or `seq(i,n)` and not `seq(i:n)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a similar approach as that of @josiber but using `dplyr` (assuming that there is a mistake in the expected output).  The first block of code i.e up to creation of "df1" is basically creating replications of "0" rows for a grouping variable "ind".  We create a n replicates  of "a" (`rep(list(a), n)`) then `rbind` it to form the matrix "a1", an index matrix "i1" of "1s" of the same dimensions as "a1".  The "i1" matrix is populated with "0" rows based on the "m1" index, and create a data.frame("df1") with a grouping variable "ind" and the other columns will be the result of "a1*i1", so that elements in "i1" that are "0" will be "0" in the output.

```
library(dplyr)
a1 <- do.call(rbind,rep(list(a),n))
i1 <- matrix(1,ncol=n,nrow=nrow(a1))
m1 <- matrix(seq(6,nrow(a1), by=n)+rep(0:3,each=4),ncol=4,byrow=TRUE)
i1[m1[upper.tri(m1,diag=TRUE)],] <- 0
df1 <- data.frame(ind=rep(1:n,each=n),a1*i1)
```

Using "df1", we use "ind" as the grouping variable (`group_by`) and summarise the columns ("X1:X5") using `summarise_each`.  We get the index of those elements in each column that have a cumulative sum greater than 14, and use that as index to get the elements of "o" (`o[which(cumsum(.)>14)..`)

```
df1 %>%
    group_by(ind)%>%
    summarise_each(funs(o[which(cumsum(.)>14)[1]]))
#  ind X1 X2 X3 X4 X5
#1   1 95 93 92 91 91
#2   2 NA 93 93 92 92
#3   3 NA 94 94 93 93
#4   4 NA 95 95 94 94
#5   5 NA NA 95 95 95
```

Or if you need a matrix output, instead of the "dplyr", create the "indx" with `Map` and use `tapply` to get the result.

```
indx <- do.call(rbind,Map(`+`,list(matrix(1:5,ncol=5,
                       nrow=5,byrow=TRUE)), seq(0,20, by=5)) )
res <- matrix(tapply(a1*i1, indx, FUN=function(x)
              o[which(cumsum(x) >14)[1]]),ncol=5,byrow=TRUE)
 res
 #     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
 #[1,]   95   93   92   91   91
 #[2,]   NA   93   93   92   92
 #[3,]   NA   94   94   93   93
 #[4,]   NA   95   95   94   94
 #[5,]   NA   NA   95   95   95
```

#### data

```
a <- matrix(1:25, nrow=5)
o <- 91:95
n <- 5
```

Comment: thanks josilber and akrun for your answers. Yes, you were right, there was a mistake in my example. I see your answers work quite well. Nonetheless I am however still just trying to get through your answer and figure out on how your function(x) and function(p) exactly work and what they calculate.

Comment: @user3472591  I updated with some explanations.  It is surprising that you commented after so many days.  I did forgot most of the steps :-)

Comment: Hey akrun. Thanks a lot. I will dig into it. Yes, I was busy with some other work. Greets.

Answer (score 2):

As I understand your question, element (i, j) of your result should contain the row identifier for the first row where the cumulative sum (i, j) + (i+1, j) + (i+2, j) + ... exceeds 14, and it should contain `NA` if that cumulative sum never exceeds 14 before reaching the bottom of the input matrix. In this case your expected output contains an error -- the rightmost two columns should be 91, 92, 93, 94, 95 instead of 91, 91, 91, 91, 91.

For each column of the input matrix (we'll operate with `apply` using margin 2) you can do a for loop (I use `sapply` as a more convenient alternative below), computing the cumulative sum of the column ignoring element above the element you're calculating:

```
a <- matrix(1:25, nrow=5)
o <- 91:95
apply(a, 2, function(x) sapply(1:length(x), function(p) {
    cs <- cumsum(x * c(rep(0, p-1), rep(1, length(x)-p+1)))
    if (max(cs > 14)) {
        return(o[min(which(cs > 14))])
    } else {
        return(NA)
    }
}))
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
# [1,]   95   93   92   91   91
# [2,]   NA   93   93   92   92
# [3,]   NA   94   94   93   93
# [4,]   NA   95   95   94   94
# [5,]   NA   NA   95   95   95
```